# Packages for writing feedback forms

Tags: packages, document-classes

I'd like to make a document that would leave ample room for the reader to fill in answers on the sheet. (nothing fancy and interactive, just whitespace for writing on the printed version)

What packages/classes exist for achieving this? I suppose I could just use massive tables and lots of `\bigskip`s but that seems suboptimal...

Here's an example of the sort of thing I want to achieve, I could add lots of space manually, but that doesn't seem ideal...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline
    Spelling & & & & & & \\ \hline
    Grammar & & & & & & \\ \hline
    Use of literature  & & & & & & \\ \hline
    Strength of Argument  & & & & & & \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/exam.html) package provides `\fillwithlines{length}` and similar commands. See section 7 of its manual.

Comment: [I ended up just doing it by hand](http://www.seamusbradley.net/2010PH220/feedback.pdf) ( [Source](http://www.seamusbradley.net/tex/feedback.tex) ), but I'll accept this answer as it has the most upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Some of those packages listed here in the TeX Catalogue could be useful: [Typesetting Exam Scripts, Quizzes, Flashcards, and Questionnaires](http://www.ctan.org/topic/exam). The already mentioned `exam` package is also listed there.